# How to compare BIGINT in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

In table `commit_time` is BIGINT and value store is like `20190508143744`
when I try to compare with `commit_time > 1000` it works without error
but when I try with `commit_time > 20190508143743`, it gives error as below

> 2019-05-29 17:35:38,390 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: For input string: "20190508143743"

Steps:

```
pig -useHCatalog

custProf = LOAD 'alisy3p.cust_change' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

// this step gives error
deviceChange= filter custProf by (commit_time > 20190508143743);
```

Also Tried:

1. `deviceChange= filter custProf by (commit_time > (bigint)20190508143743);`
2. `deviceChange= filter custProf by (commit_time > (long)20190508143743);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
deviceChange= filter custProf by (commit_time > 20190508143743**L**);

BIGINT is not supported and BIGINTEGER is different as per the documentation of hive we could use Long.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore#HCatalogLoadStore-DataTypeMappings

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html#constants

Thanks to Savagedata for his input!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Pig documentation](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.17.0/basic.html#constants), you should be able to specific a biginteger constant by adding `BI` to the end of the number. Try this:

```
deviceChange = filter custProf by (commit_time > 20190508143743BI);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didn't worked. Got error: "ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 2, column 49>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '20190508143743BI' "

Comment: Yes, biginteger is only available in Pig 0.17, so if you have an older version you would need to use long as you did in your answer.